# Using jQuery AJAX requests in a while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The following code will ask the user to enter their name, send it off to a processing script (saves to database, validates, etc) and returns a response:

```
var invalid = true;
while (invalid) {
    var name = prompt("Enter your name");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save.php",
        data: {
            "name": name
        }
    }).done(function(e) {
        //in this example, save.php returns "invalid" if the input did not pass validation
        invalid = e === "invalid";
    });
}
```

You can see the general idea I'm going for, but the problem is this:  Even if I make the AJAX call synchronous, it doesn't block the loop from continuing.  Placing a `console.log` in the `done` function reveals that the loop runs about 200 more times until my server gives a response.

The server does a heavy amount of calculations on the user's input - I'm just using name as an example here.  This cannot be done client-sided.  How can I implement this simple, beginner's design pattern across what is essentially reminding me of my multithreading nightmares in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function validate(e)
{
    if(e === "invalid")
        setTimeout(submitName, 0);
}

function submitName()
{
    var name = prompt("Enter your name");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save.php",
        data: {
            "name": name
        }
    }).done(validate);
}
```

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Sometimes Javascript is finicky and needs to be told to wait before doing something.  Using setTimeout with a delay of 0 tells the browser to wait for everything to finish before doing anything else.  Great explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/779785/382456

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Kind of, using setTimeout invokes the method on a fresh call stack.  I used it here to prevent the possibility of stack overflow or too much recursion exception.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a loop, just re-trigger the input from the done() code.  You'd probably want to name this function so it can refer to itself.

Answer (score 0):

That just worked great for me. I hope it works for you too.

```
        var invalid = true;
        while (invalid) {
            var name = prompt("Enter your name");
            console.log(Date()+' Start Loop');
            $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: {'name': name},
                 async: false,
                 url: yourURL
            }).done(function(e) {
                //in this example, save.php returns "invalid" if the input did not pass validation
                console.log(Date()+' Done()');
                invalid = (e === "invalid");
            });
            console.log(Date()+' End Loop');
        }
```